# Create a dynamic table-like grid without using tables

Tags: php, css-tables

I am wondering if it's possible to create a grid-like layout using div's that are dynamically created using PHP.

I am creating a product page that will display all products in a PHP database. I want each product to be housed in a div, and 3 divs to display in a row with as many rows as needed to get through all the products.

Something like this:

```
div              div              div
$row['product1'] $row['product2'] $row['product3']

div              div              div
$row['product4'] $row['product5'] $row['product6']
```

I would prefer not to use a table. I know how to line divs up using the float and clear properties, but not if they are all being created in a while statement, which makes me think it might not be possible.

So I guess, is this possible without using tables, or should I just stick with that?

Comment: what's wrong with a while statement? (apart from the fact that you should use foreach instead of while)

Comment: And, why not use a table to represent tabular data?

Comment: Like I said, I know how to do it using a table, but would prefer not to.

Comment: Actually this doesn't sound like tabular data. It sounds like an unordered list of products `<ul><li></li></ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done the way you ask, though it isn't the best way. It's entirely possible to identify the `<div>` positions within columns in a while loop:

```
// Looping over your results simplified...
$i = 1;
while ($results) {
   if ($i % 3 == 1) {
      $div_class = 'left';
   }  
   else if ($i % 3 == 2) {
      $div_class = 'middle';
   }
   else {
      $div_class = 'right';
   }
   $i++;

   // output, simplified
   echo "<div class='$div_class'>$row_contents</div>";
}
```

Then use your CSS to float and clear as necessary for the `left, middle, right` classes.

```
.left, .middle, .right {
   float: left;
}
.left { clear: left; }
.right { clear: right; }
```

---

### However,

Given all of this, I still probably wouldn't bother with `<div>`s.  Semantically if this is a list of products, you should be listing them in `<li>` tags. Then just style the `<li>` to `float: left;` and make each one 33% the width of the container so you get 3 per line.

Comment: this is exactly the answer for which I was looking. And of course, extremely simple once I see it. Thanks.

Comment: @sundanlotion I recommend using a `<ul>` and styling the `<li>` as I added, rather than using `<div>`s.

Comment: I'll have to look into that. You can put more than just text within <li> tags, right?

Comment: Yes you can put more than text into list elements